# Can I use Google Wallet in an Appcelerator Titanium application?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, payment, appcelerator-mobile, android-pay

Is it possible to use Google Wallet in an [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) Android/iOS application? I have searched but could not find any relevant results.

Comment: Is [In-app billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: yes In-app payment for a service.You can say travelling.